# How to query mongodb using a list of items

Tags: python, mongodb

Given the fact that I have a list of urls (stored in the variable `urls`), is it possible to make a mongodb query to get all the documents in a collection that have a key (say `url`) matching with one of those in `urls`?

I can currently do that by doing N queries to the collection (with N = len(urls)) but I'm pretty sure I'm missing a mongodb feature that allows me to do things quicker.

I must precise I've got this list of urls thanks to a mongodb query.

Here is my code (in python), the two collections are  `views` and `resources`:

```
urls = []                                              
for url in db.views.find().distinct("url"):
    urls.append(db.resources.one({'url': url}))
```

Is there a way I can make those N queries in only one?

EDIT: The final source code to do something like that is using the $in operator, like this:

```
urls = db.views.find().distinct("url")
list(db.resources.find({'url': {'$in': urls }}))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [the $in operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in)